# Python, try within while loop and Image.open

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I am trying to get my loop to continue if it encounters an error with the image file it fails. I am using PIL and checking to see if the file is a valid jpg.  I notice it is breaking when the jpg has a byte size of zero.

```
def extract_images_2():

vc = cv2.VideoCapture(videofilename)
saved_file_name=""
frame_rate=str (vc.get(cv2.cv.CV_CAP_PROP_FPS))

c=1

if vc.isOpened():
        rval , frame = vc.read()
else:
        rval = False

while rval:
        rval, frame = vc.read()
    saved_file_name=str(c) + '.jpg'
        cv2.imwrite(saved_file_name,frame)

    #Extract the image size:
    myimage= Image.open(saved_file_name)
    image_width, image_height = myimage.size
    img_new_magnitude=3

    aalib_screen_width= int(image_width/25.28)*img_new_magnitude
    aalib_screen_height= int(image_height/41.39)*img_new_magnitude

    screen = aalib.AsciiScreen(width=aalib_screen_width, height=aalib_screen_height )

        try:
                myimage= Image.open(saved_file_name).convert("L").resize(screen.virtual_size)
        except IOError:
                print ("ERROR processing ", myimage)
        continue

    screen.put_image((0,0), myimage)    

    print >> open('file.txt', 'w'), screen.render(), 2+3

    subprocess.call(["convert", "-background", "rgb(120,20,20)",  "-fill",  "rgb(255,255,0)",  "-font",  "/usr/share/fonts/truetype/freefont/FreeMonoBold.ttf",  "-pointsize", "15" , "label:@file.txt" , str(c)+'.png'])

    subprocess.call(["rm", saved_file_name ])
        c = c + 1
        cv2.waitKey(1)

vc.release()

subprocess.call(["ffmpeg", "-r",  frame_rate, "-b", "320k", "-i", "%d.gif","-vcodec", "libx264", "output.mp4" ])
```

[ SOLVED SOLUTION ]

http://pastebin.com/WackucCg

I had to past it there because the formatting was messed up when I paste it here.

Comment: `continue` moves to the next iteration of the loop. You need to move the `continue` statement within the `except IOError`, after the `print`. Your code currently will not execute past the continue, ever.

Comment: Please fix the indentation of the code, and explain exactly how it is breaking --- do you get an unexpected exception?

Comment: Also, if you find a solution yourself, don't include it in the question, write it as an answer instead (where it belongs).